# Javascript/jQuery, if and else statements both being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not too sure what's going on here and feel I may be missing something that is probably quite obvious, but I have an if else in which both statements are being called. If someone could shed some light on this that would be great. The code below is using asual and should be detecting whether or not a div  `$('#' + $.address.hash()` has already been loaded. However both if and else events are being fired in order. In fact the else statement fires twice...

```
$('#lmit_back').show(400, function() {
    if($('#' + $.address.hash() ).length == 0) {
        $('#init').load('inithandler.php', { 'address' : $.address.hash() }, function() {
            $('#' + $.address.hash()).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $('#remn').load('pagehandler.php',{ 'address' : $.address.hash() });
            });
        });
    }  
    else {
        alert('hey');
    }
});
```

Here is all the code..I can't really work out what could cause it to execute twice, unless it has something to do with address.change which im not as familiar with as I would like to be.

if (($.address.hash() == '')) {$.address.hash('home');}

```
    $('#lmit_back').click(function() {

            $.address.hash('home');

    });


    $.address.change( function() {  



        if (!($.address.hash() == 'home')) 
        {



        var exception = '.' + $('[href="#' + $.address.hash() + '"]').parent().attr('class');


            $('#left_menu_bar li:not(' + exception + ')').hide(300,function() {

                $(exception).show( function() {

                    $('#left_menu_bar').animate({ width:'100%'},400, function() { 

                        $('#lmit_back').show(400, function() {


                                if ($('#' + $.address.hash() ).length === 0)
                                {

                                    $('#init').load('inithandler.php', { 'address' : $.address.hash() } , function() { 

                                        $('#' + $.address.hash()).fadeIn(1000, function() {

                                            $('#remn').load('pagehandler.php',{ 'address' : $.address.hash() });

                                        });



                                    });

                                }
                                else
                                {

                                alert('nigs');

                                }

                        });

                    });

                });

            });



        }
        else
        {




            $('#left_menu_bar').animate({ width:'251px'}, function() { 

                $('#left_menu_bar li').show( function() {

                    $('#lmit_back').hide();

                });

            });



            $('#left_menu_bar').css('width','251px');



        }


    });
```

Comment: Try replacing `==` with `===` and check?

Comment: putting your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ helps the people answering your question tremendously.

Comment: I suspect you are executing the code more than once.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Gave it a go, results are the same. :(

Comment: Hm, when I replace if ($('#' + $.address.hash() ).length === 0) with if (!$('#' + $.address.hash() ).length === 0) the alert statement fires first as expected, then the if statement, but it fires 4 times...

Comment: Where is that code called from? Please show it in context. (And don't worry about testing `.length` in other ways, `.length == 0` will work.)

Comment: The code is called from asual's address.change event, it then checks to see whether or not the change is to the homepage or to another page. If it is NOT the homepage, the rest of the code, including that above executes

Comment: also the comment I made just before was incorrect, with if (!$('#' + $.address.hash() ).length === 0) , only the else statement fires, and does so 4 times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is not arising from the code you have pasted.  The only way the code could be running multiple times and hitting multiple branches is if it is being executed more than once.  Look to the surrounding code for places where this could be called more than once.

Comment: hmm okay thanks, I've got a feeling it may have something to do with asuals address.change ill take a closer look

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue, while debugging when if condition was true it also went in else block. Later I added alert and console.log in `if/else` block's & realized, else was not actually being executed but while debugging it looked like it was in else.

So, whoever faces same issue verify by adding `alert` or `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same behavior, when I debugged step by step it worked. It ended up being that I was attaching multiple click events so the code fired n times.